# StackArray Generic class does not work

Tags: java, arrays, stack

I am beginner in Java and trying to write a StackArray. I have a tester to test my code. I have run it several times but it does not pass my push method and my search method. Can anyone give me an idea where I am doing wrong? Thank you so much in advance!

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Stack<E> implements StackADT<E>{

    private E a[];
    private int head, size;

    public Stack(){

    }

    /*Adds the specified element to the top of the stack.
      Returns the item added.*/
    public E push(E element){
       if (a.length == size){
           throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot add to full stack");
    }

            // Since the remainder of the stack is to the RIGHT of the stack,
            // adding a new element pushes the head to the LEFT (+ wrap around)
        //head = (head - 1 + a.length) % a.length;
      return  a[head++] = element;
          //  return element;
    }

    /*Removes and returns the element from the top of the stack*/
    public E pop(){
        if (empty()){
            throw new java.util.EmptyStackException();
        }

            // We need to get a copy of the old head before we advance to the
            // new head. We want to return the old head, not the new head.
            E rval = a[head];

            // Why DON'T we need to add a.length here like we did in push?
            head = (head + 1) % a.length;

            return rval;

    }

    /*Returns without removing the element at the top of the stack*/
    public E peek(){
        if (empty()){
            throw new java.util.EmptyStackException();
        }

        return a[head];
    }

    /*Returns true if the stack is empty, false otherwise*/
    public boolean empty(){
        return size == 0;
    }

    /*Returns the 1-based position where an object is on this stack
    This means If the object o occurs as an item in this stack, this
    method returns the distance FROM THE TOP OF THE STACK of the
    occurrence nearest the top of the stack - the topmost item on
    the stack is considered to be at distance 1.*/
    public int search(Object o){
        // i is the LOGICAL index
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            // p is the PHYSICAL index
            int p = (head + i) % a.length;
            E e = a[p];

            // e == o   Are the items (null or non-null the same?)
                // if they are not the same, then at least one of them
                // is non-null and can be compared to the other.
            if (e == o || e != null && e.equals(o)){
                // Distance = logical index + 1 as per the above description
                return i + 1;
            }
        }

        // No match was made
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }

    /*Returns a string representation of the queue*/
    public String toString(){
        // Output should look like: [e_0, e_1, ..., e_n-1]
        // Empty stack: []

        if (empty())
            return "[]";

        // We know that there is at least one element in this stack
            // since we didn't return
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append("[").append(a[head]);

        // Start on the SECOND logical index
        for (int i = 1; i < size; i++){
            int p = (head + i) % a.length;
            E e = a[p];

            b.append(", ").append(e);
        }
        b.append("]");
        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned i am new to java programming, so If you see silly mistakes let me know where it is! I am not looking for answers, I am trying to learn!!!

Comment: You do not initialize your instance variables `a`, `head` and `size`. The first, an array-type, defaults to `null` (which will lead to a NPE when calling `push`) while the others default to `0`, which is probably okay for `size`; I don't know what `head` is supposed to represent though. I'd interpret it as the first element (head) of the stack, but then its type should be `E` and not `int` in which case it will default to `null`. **Edit**: Hmmm... if `head` is supposed to be the index of the first element, then `int` is fine, but on an empty stack, I'd say the index is negative.

Answer (score 0):

The most prominent error is that you do not instantiate the instance variables of `Stack`. Java uses default values for non-initialized values: primitive numbers are set to `0`, booleans are set to `false` and all reference-types (i.e., Arrays and Objects) are set to `null`. This means that `head` and `size` are both initialized to `0` while `a` is initialized to `null`. The latter yields a `NullPointerException` when dereferencing its content.

Assuming you want to keep an array as your internal representation, you'd have to initialize an instance of `E[]` somehow. Unfortuantely, you cannot call `new E[size]`. See **[this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)** on how to instantiate a generic array.

As for the initial value of `head`, which seems to be supposed to point to the top of the stack, you are not consistent in how you want to use it: In `push`, you use `head` as the index of the next free element in `a` and increment its value after adding the element. In `toString`, `peek` and `pop`, you use `head` as the index of the element that you want to return. Either representation is okay, but you must not mix them up.

---

Assuming you want `head` to always point to the last element, you would initialize it to `-1` and increment its value in the `push`-method before accessing the index in `a`. Note the difference between `head++` and `++head`:

```
int i = head++;
```

is equivalent to

```
int i = head; 
head = head + 1;
```

while

```
int i = ++head;
```

is equivalent to

```
head = head + 1; 
int i = head;
```

so as a fix, you could change

```
return  a[head++] = element;
```

to

```
return  a[++head] = element;
```

but it is probably better to add a few lines of code and make the logic more explicit by incrementing the value of `head` first.

---

Now that we covered initialization, there's also a bug regarding the value of `size`: `push` should increment the size of the stack while `pop` should decrement it: However, in your code, `size` is never modified, hence `empty` is always true.

Also, I don't quite understand the idea behind the line

```
// Why DON'T we need to add a.length here like we did in push?
head = (head + 1) % a.length;
```

in `pop`. As an element is removed (and not added) I'd say this should simply be `head = head - 1` or `head--` if you prefer postfix-operators.

#### Putting it all together

Initialize the Stack properly, e.g.,

```
private E a[];
private int head = -1;
private int size = 0;

public Stack(Class<E> c, int maxSize){
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    final E[] a = (E[]) Array.newInstance(c, maxSize);
    this.a = a;
}
```

Update the value of `size` in `push` and fix the update to `head`:

```
public E push(E element){
    if (a.length == size){
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot add to full stack");
    }
    size++; 
    return a[++head] = element;
}
```

Update the value of `size` and `head` in `pop`:

```
public E pop(){
    if (empty()){
        throw new java.util.EmptyStackException();
    }
    size--;
    return a[head--];
}
```

#### Fixing toString

**Remark:** I kind of ignored the comments, as comments tend to lie as code gets refactored; but I just noticed that you wrote in a comment:

```
// Since the remainder of the stack is to the RIGHT of the stack,
// adding a new element pushes the head to the LEFT (+ wrap around)
```

which is actually the opposite of what the next line in your code tells: `return  a[head++] = element;`. The proposed bugfixes are based on the code, not the comment, hence the remainder of the stack is to the LEFT of `head`. Because of that, the implementation of `toString` must be changed to print the array from right to left instead of left to right:

```
public String toString(){
    if (empty())
        return "[]";
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    b.append("[").append(a[head]);

    for (int i = head - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        E e = a[i];
        b.append(", ").append(e);
    }
    b.append("]");
    return b.toString();
}
```